# C# web api data filtration

Tags: c#, api, rest, filtering

Good day,
I am doing Web api rest project and want to include product search for products by size and color, but I want to be able search for example:
1 One size

```
[httpGet][Route("oneSize/{sizeID}")]
```

2 Two Sizes

```
[httpGet][Route("TwoSizes/{sizeID1}/{sizeID2}")]
```

3 One size/ One color

```
[httpGet][Route("OneSizeOneColor/{sizeID1}/{ColorID}")]
```

4 Two sizes/ One color

```
[httpGet][Route("TwoSizeOneColor/{sizeID1}/{sizeID2}/{ColorID}")]
```

etc.
Do I need to create end point for every tipe of search or is there a smarter way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the query params. You can add them via `FromQuery` attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchProducts([FromQuery] int[] sizeIds, [FromQuery] int[] colorIds) {
}
```

You can replace `int` with `string` if you have string Ids.

For example, if you want to make a request with sizes 1 and 2, and color 3 and 4, the request would look like this: `https://localhost:5001/your-endpoint-name?sizeIds=1&sizeIds=2&colorIds=3&colorIds=4`

So query is a list of `key=value` url parameters after the `?` separated by `&` sign

EDIT

You can easily query the database with the sql IN operator.

In EF Core, it would look something like this:

```
IQuaryable<Product> query = dbContext.Products;
if (sizeIds.Length > 0) {
    query= query.Where(p => sizeIds.Contains(p.SizeId));
}
if (colorIds.Length > 0) {
    query= query.Where(p => colorIds.Contains(p.ColorId));
}
List<Product> result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

It would be translated to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Products.SizeId IN (1, 2) AND Products.ColorId IN (3, 4);
```

Comment: And what about repository calls? Do now i have to create for each possible call or it also have some other way?

Comment: You can easily query the database with the sql IN operator
I updated the answer

Comment: Could you check my answer and could you tell me how it could work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have nested classess

```
 public class ProductBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductVariant> Variants { get; set; } = new List<ProductVariant>();
    public int BaseImageId { get; set; } = 0;
    public string BaseImagePath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}

 public class ProductVariant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductBaseId { get; set; }
    public int ProductSizeId { get; set; }
    public ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }
    public int ProductColorId { get; set; }
    public ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ImageVariant> imageVariants { get; set; } = new List<ImageVariant>();
}
public class ProductSize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
public class ProductColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying something like this

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Models.ProductBase>> SearchProducts(int[] SizeIds, int[]  ColorIds )
    {
        IQueryable<Models.ProductBase> query = _dataContext.ProductBases
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.ProductSize)
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.ProductColor)
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.imageVariants);
           
        if(SizeIds.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(pb => SizeIds.Contains(pb.Variants.Any(pb.Variants.doesnotWork));
        }
        if(ColorIds.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(pb => ColorIds.Contains(pb.Variants.Contains(pb.Variants.doesNotWork)));
        }

        List<ProductBase> result = await query.ToListAsync(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed  , this is working now

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.ProductBase>> SearchProducts(int[] SizeIds, int[]  ColorIds )
    {
        IQueryable<Models.ProductBase> query = _dataContext.ProductBases
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.ProductSize)
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.ProductColor)
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants).ThenInclude(v => v.imageVariants);
           
        if(SizeIds.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(pb => pb.Variants.ToList().Any(v => SizeIds.Contains(v.ProductSizeId)));
        }
        if(ColorIds.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(pb => pb.Variants.ToList().Any(v => ColorIds.Contains(v.ProductColorId)));
        }

        List<Models.ProductBase> result = await query.ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
```